# How to get "AM/PM" in in date string?

Tags: php, datetime

I want to get the current time, in Hour:Min AM/PM format can any one help me in this. I have these code  `date('h:i')` to get hour and minute, but dont get AM/PM. Anybody help me?

Comment: Sure, here you go http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: (This question really isn't *that* bad.. and doesn't deserve so many downvotes.)

Comment: @user2864740: It is bad, since everything he was asking was written in the php manual. I bet he didn't even bother using google.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Which close vote do you choose? If there is none, it probably isn't *that* bad of a question. If you do choose one, please vote accordingly. (There are *many* questions which are trivially answered by looking at the API documentation or specification; I think it is prudent to politely explain the problem/solution and link relevant resources, especially to someone who is new to SO. The number of downvotes this questions received is ridiculous.)

Comment: @user2864740: It's just a proof for that most of the users here asking things can't look into the API documention or using google.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois It is still unwarranted for the number of downvotes without supporting close votes. (I never said vote *for* the question, but I think it is important to exercise prudence when downvoting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple use of date function

```
echo date("g:i A");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `A` in `date()` function

```
echo date('h:i A');
```